# JWT Scala: Key bytes may only be specified for HMAC signatures. If using RSA or Elliptic Curve, use the signWith() method instead

Tags: scala, jwt, rs256

I am using Scala to generate JWT using `RS256` algorithm and private keys:

```
val jwtPayload = s"""{
                        |    "exp": $time,
                        |    "iss": "$orgId",
                        |    "sub": "$technicalAccountId",
                        |    "aud": "${imsExp}/c/${clientId}",
                        |    "${imsExp}/s/${metaScope}": true
                        |}""".stripMargin
    println(jwtPayload)
    val token = Jwts.builder()
      .setPayload(jwtPayload)
      .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256,privateKey.getBytes("UTF-8"))
```

But this fails with the error:

```
Key bytes may only be specified for HMAC signatures.  If using RSA or Elliptic Curve, use the signWith(SignatureAlgorithm, Key) method instead.
    at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:38)
```

But the same code works well in javascript:

```
const jwtPayload = {
        exp: Math.round(300 + Date.now() / 1000),
        iss: secrets.org,
        sub: secrets.id,
        aud: `${secrets.imsEndpoint}/c/${secrets.technicalAccount.clientId}`,
        [`${secrets.imsEndpoint}/s/${secrets.metascopes}`]: true
    };

    let token;
    try {
        token = jwt.sign(
            jwtPayload,
            { key: secrets.privateKey},
            { algorithm: 'RS256' }
        );
        console.log(token);
    } catch (tokenError) {
        return Promise.reject(tokenError);
    }
```

I am unable to identify two things:

1. How to pass passphrase?
2. How to get rid of below error:

```
Key bytes may only be specified for HMAC signatures.  If using RSA or Elliptic Curve, use the signWith(SignatureAlgorithm, Key) method instead.
    at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:38)
```

When I remove `.getBytes` method, I recieve a new error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Base64-encoded key bytes may only be specified for HMAC signatures.  If using RSA or Elliptic Curve, use the signWith(SignatureAlgorithm, Key) method instead.
```

Comment: Did you try removing the `.getBytes("UTF-8"))`? The error message seems to recommend this: *If using RSA or Elliptic Curve, use the signWith(SignatureAlgorithm, Key) method instead.*

Comment: I did try to remove `.getBytes` but then I recieve a new error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Base64-encoded key bytes may only be specified for HMAC signatures.  If using RSA or Elliptic Curve, use the signWith(SignatureAlgorithm, Key) method instead.
`